# Google Maps SDK for IOS - Marker always centered

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im trying to develop an app that lets the user change its position on a map. I actually have a marker that repaints its position to the map camera on a mapView:didChangeCameraPosition event and it works ok, but the problem i see is that performance is not good enough since the marker   is repainted in the map with some delay.

I would like to know if there is a better approach to implement this requirement

here is my actual code:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {
      self.marker.position = position.target;  
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you just add a `UIImageView` with the marker, over the top of the `GMSMapView`, positioned in the middle of it?

Comment: I guess he might need the callout that comes with a marker

Comment: @Nerkatel Yeah, but then he could do the callout manually too.

Comment: It could work but, isnt there a way that involves the use of GMSMarker directly? i ask cause i also need this marker to be at some static position in the map when some action is triggered

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *strLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_message.latitude];
NSString *strLong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_message.longitude];
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@center=%@,%@&zoom=15&size=200x200&markers=color:red%%7Clabel:C%%7C%@,%@&key=%@",https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?,strLat,strLong,strLat,strLong,GOOGLE_API_BROWSER_KEY];
NSLog(@"strURL %@",strURL);
strURL = [strURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%%" withString:@"%"];
```